# Using setInterval with XML parsing

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, setinterval

I have two tables in my HTML, each one running a separate script to parse data from an XML sheet. I'm trying to figure out how to place a setInterval function so that both scripts will reload the XML data every 30000 milliseconds (30 seconds) when the XML file and HTML file are both put onto an FTP server.

Everywhere I've attempted to place the function just causes whatever table it's on to break.

Script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlDoc=null;
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
}
else if (document.implementation.createDocument)
{
xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
}
else
{
alert('Your browser cannot handle this script');
}
if (xmlDoc!=null)
{
xmlDoc.async=false;
xmlDoc.load("test.xml");

document.write("<table border='1'>");

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Arena");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Team")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td>");

document.write("<td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Field")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td>");

document.write("<td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Score")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlDoc=null;
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
}
else if (document.implementation.createDocument)
{
xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
}
else
{
alert('Your browser cannot handle this script');
}
if (xmlDoc!=null)
{
xmlDoc.async=false;
xmlDoc.load("test.xml");

document.write("<table border='1'>");

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Flag");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Team")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
}

</script>
```

And the setInterval I want to implement:

```
setInterval(function() {
}, 30000);
```

Alternatively, if the best way to do this involves merging both scripts together into one (while still keeping the tables separate), please let me know.

Comment: I think first, you should modernize your code as you are doing things like we did it in 2005. `type="text/javascript"` hasn't been needed for years. The entire `if (window.ActiveXObject)` statement can be replaced with just `xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest()` since all browsers have implemented XHR natively for years as well. Get rid of all the `document.write()` statements and just use the `responseXml` from the AJAX call to update an existing DOM element. Lastly, don't use tables for layout.

Comment: You also haven't configured the XHR completely - - you didn't set up a success callback and you aren't actually attempting to use it's response anywhere. You should really read about [how AJAX requests work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The reason this code is written the way it is is because I normally don't work with XML, and approached this with a "whatever works" mentality. I tried using xmlDoc = XMLHttpRequest() before and didn't get it to work right. My only concern right now is getting the JS function to work properly. (And unfortunately, my task requires me to build this in tables.)

Comment: With the code the way it is, it isn't going to work anywhere but older versions of IE, because only older versions of IE support that ActiveX control. And if you look at my comment and/or the link I shared, you'll see that the reason your code didn't work was because you didn't use `new` as I showed. Read the link I shared. It has many examples and will explain how AJAX works. Your code is miles away from working.

Comment: I understand that. If this were a more involved project, I would look towards overhauling everything but for the simple purposes it serves, it works fine on the FTP. Right now, the only thing I'm asking is whether or not setInterval is compatible with this code. If it isn't, then I will sincerely take your suggestion and redo it.